# Unable to establish connection with data source with Teradata. Missing settings: {[DBCName]}

Tags: odbc, teradata, unixodbc, isql

I'am installed Teradata driver on CentOS as described in official README. 
After installation drivers is located in `/opt/teradata/client`

```
/ODBC_32/
/ODBC_64/
```

Each folder has subfolders and files

```
include
lib
locale
odbc.ini
odbcinst.ini
```

Using ODBC_64 driver, I'am copied contents from `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` into `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini` files respectively.

Now in `/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[ODBC]
InstallDir=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64
Trace=no
Pooling=yes

[ODBC Data Sources]
Teradata_ODBC_DSN=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20

[Teradata_ODBC_DSN]
Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
DBCName=My_Teradata_Server_IP
UID=
PWD=
```

in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[ODBC Drivers]
Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20=Installed

[Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20]
Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
CPTimeout=60
```

But, when I'am tested connection with command `isql -v Teradata_ODBC_DSN` it show me an error `[08001][unixODBC][Teradata][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[DBCName]}`

DBCName option is filled as you can see above. Why such error is appear?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the `ODBCINI` variable to your *.ini* file.
Try the below and then test:

```
export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
echo $ODBCINI
```